# deserializacion de matriz de array con swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, swift4

Hola es que tengo un array bidemensional y pues me gustaría recuperar el nombre de cada subarray y con sicha información hacer un nuevo array para llenar los datos de una celda, este es mi array

```
[{"id":"76","nombre":"Edward Bernal","puesto":"M\u00e9dico Holcim","telefono":"321 2191103","idcategoria":"2","idplanta":"9"},{"id":"294","nombre":"Harold Franco","puesto":"Gerente H&S","telefono":"313 8886786","idcategoria":"2","idplanta":"9"},{"id":"305","nombre":"John L\u00f3pez","puesto":"Coordinador H&S RMX","telefono":"313 8886815","idcategoria":"2","idplanta":"9"},{"id":"306","nombre":"Lina Franky","puesto":"Cordinador RRHH Local","telefono":"321 9388000","idcategoria":"2","idplanta":"9"},{"id":"75","nombre":"Luisa Gil","puesto":"Responsable de H&S ","telefono":"310 5516656","idcategoria":"2","idplanta":"9"},{"id":"133","nombre":"Viviana Salazar","puesto":"Jefe de Planta","telefono":"313 8283644","idcategoria":"2","idplanta":"9"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que tenes ahí es un JsonArray, lo que te conviene en estos casos es modelizar.

Este es el json que te viene

```
"id":"76",
"nombre":"Edward Bernal",
"puesto":"Médico Holcim",
"telefono":"321 2191103",
"idcategoria":"2",
"idplanta":"9"
```

Con esto podes construir un struct que sea Codable para que lo puedas parsear muy facilmente.

Aca te pongo un ejemplo que extraje de alguno de mis proyectos, solo le cambie el nombre a las propiedades para que coincidan, espero que te sirva.

```
struct Trabajador : Codable {

  var id : String?
  var nombre : String?
  var telefono : String?
  var idcategoria : String?
  var idplanta: String?

  init(json:Data) {
      do {
          let decoder = JSONDecoder()
          decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
          self = try decoder.decode(Trabajador.self, from: json)
      }catch{
          print("parser error")
      }
  }

  static func getTrabajadores(jsonArray : Data) -> [Trabajador]?{
      do {
          let decoder = JSONDecoder()
          decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
          let array = try decoder.decode([Trabajador].self, from: jsonArray)
          return array
      }catch{
          return nil
      }
  }

}
```